# Comment utiliser l'expression "sachant"

Tags: verbes, participe-présent, gérondif

J'entends tout le temps le mot "sachant" quand des Français expliquent quelque chose. Je sais qu'il veut dire "knowing that" mais je ne sais pas vraiment comment l'utiliser. Est-ce que je peux l'utiliser toujours si j'explique quelque chose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I**

Une façon de l'utiliser est bien celle du contexte d'une explication que l'on donne ; on s'en sert pour formuler une donnée de départ dans un raisonnement, soit un raisonnement courant, qui peut être d'une simplicité enfantine, ou même compliqué, soit un raisonnement formel en mathématiques.

- Sachant que le soleil produisait rapidement des lésions sur sa peau elle s'est enduit les bras de crème solaire.
- Sachant que vous n'aurez plus un sou dans trois jours si vous continuez à dépenser autant et (sachant)  qu'il faut que vous déboursiez un billet d'avion pour votre retour, pourquoi ne gardez vous pas votre argent ?
- Sachant que 3 divise 21 et sachant que 21 divise 105 on conclut que 3 divise 105, d'après le théorème que nous venons de prouver. (*Le théorème n'est rien d'autre que la généralisation de cette assertion avec une preuve montrant que c'est une assertion vrai.*)

**II**

Un autre contexte d'utilisation est celui des assertions que quelqu'un sait quelque chose. La locution qui résulte est alors équivalente à une relative avec « qui ». Dans ce contexte-ci, l'emploi est plus particulier à la langue écrite, comme pour toutes les propositions participiales.

- Il y avait quelqu'un dans l'équipe, sachant peu de choses, mais qui était vaillant, très vaillant, et je le connaissais.
- Il y avait quelqu'un dans l'équipe, qui savait peu de choses, mais qui était vaillant, très vaillant, et je le connaissais. (*On utiliserais plutôt la présente forme dans une conversation.*)

**III**

Une forme alternative d'utilisation est dans un gérondif, que l'on obtient en faisant précéder le participe présent de la préposition « en ». C'est une forme qui exprime la simultanéité. Cette forme peut remplacer le participe présent dans certains cas seulement.

- Tout en sachant qu'il n'arriverait pas à décrocher le pompon, il s'évertuait à étendre son bras aussi haut et aussi vite que possible. (*« sachant » tout seul ne convient pas dans cette phrase, mais il convient exactement dans la prochaine.*)
- (*Sachant qu'il n'arriverait pas à décrocher le pompon s'il restait assis, il se juchait sur le cheval de bois pour y parvenir quand même.*)
- C'est en sachant que le criminel pouvait l'apercevoir et la tuer aussi qu'elle s'est élancée au dehors pour donner l'alerte.

Les locutions « tout en sachant » et « c'est en sachant » sont courantes dans le présent contexte.

Answer (score 6):

Cela dépend de la situation. Le mot `Sachant` vient de `savoir`. Les Français utilisent essentiellement ce mot lorsqu'ils détaillent un savoir, quelque chose qui se sait. Par exemple:

> Quand penses-tu que je reverrai John, sachant qu'il est parti hier ?

Dans cette phrase, on utilise le mot `sachant` pour pointer le fait qu'on sait que John est parti. Le mot est utilisé comme si l'individu à qui l'on parle sait que John est parti.
Le mot est souvent utilisé quand un problème est posé. Par exemple:

> J'ai 16 bonbons. Sachant que j'en mange 2 par jour, au bout de combien de jour n'aurais-je plus de bonbons ?

Dans cette situation, on met de nouveau l'accent sur le fait que notre interlocuteur sait qu'on en mange 2 par jour. Mais lorsque l'on explique quelque chose, il est plus intéressant d'utiliser le mot `sachant`.

Pour répondre à ta question: cela dépend de la situation. Lorsque tu poses un problème, tu peux l'utiliser. Mais il est plus compliqué de l'utiliser quand tu expliques quelque chose à quelqu'un. Dans mes deux exemples, les phrases se terminent par une question. Par exemple:

> A midi j'ai mangé une salade, sachant qu'hier j'ai mangé un steak.

Cette phrase ne sonne pas correct. On aura plus tendance à dire:

> A midi j'ai mangé une salade, alors qu'hier j'ai mangé un steak.